# How can we make if statement in R evaluate a vector of logical values without using ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to generate a summary for each column in a dataset with a function. The main idea is below

```
function(col){
##if numeric
##return class, percentage of NAs, percentage of zeros etc

##else if column's values contain TRUE or FALSE
  else if(toupper(unique(col)) %in% c('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
##return class="logical", percentage of NAs, percentage of zeros etc

##else if character & not contain TRUE or FALSE
##return class, percentage of NAs, percentage of zeros etc

##else
##return class="Date",percentage of NAs, percentage of zeros etc
}
```

However, the part

```
else if(toupper(unique(col)) %in% c('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
```

gives back an error

```
the condition has lengh>1 and only the first value will be used
```

To my understanding, why we are having this error is that

```
(toupper(unique(col))
```

gives back a vector of logical values and `if statement` can only evaluate a single `TRUE`or `FALSE`. Only the first row will be evaluated. For my purpose, only evaluating the first row is enough, but I wonder how should we rewrite this so R understands that I want to know if the whole column contains any `TRUE`or`FALSE`?

Comment: use the `any` function: `else if(any(toupper(unique(col)) %in% c('TRUE', 'FALSE')))` (If you are testing whether any element is in the given vector, `unique` is unnecessary.

Comment: Side question: does your data contain literal strings `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` which happen to mimic R's logical constants `TRUE` and `FALSE`, or are you try to determine if there is something other than one of those two values in a `logical` vector?

Comment: @r2evans the data contains `"TRUE"`and `"FALSE"` in some character columns, so I have to manually set `class` to logical. Thanks for the help!